# One SQL query, two records?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mariadb

I trying to fetch data from two related tables using a foreign key and keep the data as separate records / objects.

The best solution I have found so far is using JOINs with column prefixing to differentiate between the two tables.

```
SELECT
  tableA.method AS tableA_method,
  tableB.primitiveType AS tableB_primitiveType
FROM tableB
JOIN tableA ON tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
WHERE tableB.id = ?
```

This works, but means I have to split the data after the query is completed. Is there a way to perform a single SQL query that returns separate records for each table's data?

Current result: A single object/RowDataPacket with columns from both tables

```
[ RowDataPacket { tableA_method: "some value", tableB_primitiveType: "some value }]
```

Desired result: Two objects, one for each table

```
[ RowDataPacket { method: "some value" }, RowDataPacket { primitiveType: "some value" }]
```

or

```
[ RowDataPacket { tableA: { method: "some value" }, tableB: { primitiveType: "some value }}]
```

I've looked into subqueries, but they involve multiple queries and might not be the most efficient solution.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? What do you mean with "keep the data as separate records / objects"? Maybe a result now and a result which you want would help aswell

Comment: @Silvan : I made a clarification in the question.

Comment: AFAIK, a single SELECT statement can only return one result set.  However, a stored procedure can return multiple result sets, so you might want to investigate that.

Comment: Please show both sample data and the expected result

Comment: @JonasMetzler. I have clarified the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want makes only sense if the two tables have the same column. Let's say tableA has a column name and tableB as well. You can now JOIN them but then you get 2 columns. If you want to "merge" the result set you can use UNION.

```
SELECT name FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT name FROM tableB
```

A single SELECT statement is not capable of returning different result sets from different tables. But why should it do that? You can just run 2 different SELECTS.

Comment: Thank you @Silvan. I have no interest in merging data from the two tables. I just wanted to know if you can get back two objects (one for each table) from a single query. Since the foreign key allows you to get the data in a single object, placing it in two separate objects seemed like only a small step from there. But I gather from your answer that this is in fact not possible.

Comment: I don't know how experienced you are in SQL because I am a little worried about the use of the word object in your texts. SQL does not operate on "objects" rather on tables. And the result is sort of a table as well. In a table every row needs to have the same amount of columns.

Comment: I have very limited experience! When I say object, I'm referring to the RowDataPacket in the query result. It might look like this: [ RowDataPacket { tableA_method: "some value", tableB_primitiveType: "some value }]. I was hoping you could get something like: [ RowDataPacket { method: "some value" }, RowDataPacket { primitiveType: "some value" }] or this: [ RowDataPacket { tableA: { method: "some value" }, tableB: { primitiveType: "some value }}]

Comment: Yes this is not possible. You have to run 2 different queries. If you want to get a feeling to why try write some SQL's inside an SQL tool like DataSpell or some other tool. You will get the hang out of it pretty quickly!

Comment: Okay, it is what it is. I hope so!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a stored procedure to execute your two queries in one go.

Set up:

```
DELIMITER // ;
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure (IN tableB_id INT)
       BEGIN

          SELECT tableA.*
          FROM tableA
          INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id
          WHERE tableB.id = tableB_id;

          SELECT tableB.*
          FROM tableB
          WHERE tableB.id = tableB_id;

       END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, whenever you want to return your two result sets with a single call - for example for an id of 123, you can use:

```
CALL myProcedure(123);
```

Comment: Thank you @RobEyre! It's not exactly what I was hoping for, but I will try it out nonetheless.